# I am writing a program that converts knots to different measurements but I am getting a NameError "" is not defined

Tags: python, function, nameerror

I am trying to call a function using a parameter but when it is put into another function, the parameter says it is not defined

I tried changing the parameter to multiple different things but nothing has worked.

```
from os import system


def main():
  system("clear")
  user_input = input("What was your speed in knots? ")
  if user_input.isdigit():
    knots = int(user_input)
    print(to_mph(knots), "mp/h")
    print(to_kmh(knots), "km/h", show_results(r_kmh))
  while not user_input.isdigit():
    print("Invalid response.")
    user_input = input("What was your speed in knots?")
    knots = int(user_input)


def to_mph(knots):
  mph = 1.1507 * knots
  r_mph = round(mph, 1)
  return r_mph


def to_kmh(knots):
  kmh = 1.852 * knots
  r_kmh = round(kmh, 1)
  return r_kmh


def show_results(r_kmh):
  if r_kmh < 60:
    kmh60 = print(" mp/h - Go faster")
    return kmh60
  elif r_kmh >= 60 and r_kmh < 100:
    print(" mp/h - Nice one.")
  elif r_kmh >= 100 and r_kmh < 120:
    print(" mp/h - Radical!")
  elif r_kmh >= 120:
    print(" mp/h - Whoa! Slow down!")
  else:
    print("Please enter in your speed in knots")


#keep this at the very bottom of your program
if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

```
Error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 46, in <module>
    main()
  File "main.py", line 11, in main
    print(to_kmh(knots), "km/h", show_results(r_kmh))
NameError: name 'r_kmh' is not defined. Did you mean: 'to_kmh'?
```

Comment: The error message tells you exactly what's wrong.  Look at the call to `show_results`, which is `show_results(r_kmh)`.  It's trying to pass the value of the variable `r_kmh`.  But oops, you forgot to give `r_kmh` a value, so there is no `r_kmh` variable.  Bug.  Either pass a different variable, or else define it before trying to use is.   For example, `r_kmh = to_kmh(knots)` will define it as a variable.

Comment: But you probably don't want to print it the way you are, since you're *already* printing the rounded kmh value in that `print` call.  Instead, you probably intended to call it outside of the `print`.  But `show_results` has its own problems.  For example, why is it trying to use the return value from a `print` call as the value of `kmh60`?  That makes no sense.  `print()` always returns `None`.  In fact, `show_results` will always return `None`, so its return value is useless.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working code for your problem.rather than using while loop to validate the input try **exception handling** later will help much. the print statement in the `show_results` function return none because of return value is not defined so rather than printing the result you need to return the result. when the second time the `while not user_input.isDigit()` is validating the `knots = int(user_input)` gives and exception if you enter a invalid response again.

```
def main():
    while True:
        try:
            user_input = int(input("What was your speed in knots? "))
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid Response.")
            continue
        else:
            break
    knots = int(user_input)
    print(to_mph(knots),"mp/h")
    print("{} km/h {}".format(to_kmh(knots),show_results(to_kmh(knots))))
   


def to_mph(knots):
    mph = 1.507 * knots
    return round(mph,1)

def to_kmh(knots):
    kmh = 1.852 * knots
    return round(kmh,1)


def show_results(speed):
    if speed < 60:
       return " mp/h - Go Faster"
    elif speed >= 60 and speed <= 100:
        return " mp/h - Nice one."
    elif speed >= 100 and speed <= 120:
        return " mp/h - Radical!"
    elif speed >= 120:
        return " mp/h - Whoa! Slow down!"
    else:
        return "Please enter in your speed in knots"

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```